# Dashed svg rect as background of 100% parent sizes

Tags: css, svg

how can i draw dashed rounded rect without cutting?

My case:

```css
.button{
  position: relative;
  background: #CE3900;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 30px;
  color: #FC961E;
}

.button:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px;
  left: 6px;
  width: calc(100% - 12px);
  height: calc(100% - 12px);;
  background: #ffffff22 url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg width='100%' height='100%' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><rect rx='20px' width='100%' height='100%' style='fill: none; stroke: %23FC961E; stroke-width: 4px; stroke-dasharray: 4 12; stroke-linecap: round'/></svg>") no-repeat;
  }
```

```html
<div class="button">I am button</div>
```

You see, that stroke's width is cutted in half. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution https://jsfiddle.net/1t4qgrbs/. But I am not sure that this is correct solution

```css
.button{
  position: relative;
  background: #CE3900;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 30px;
  color: #FC961E;
}

.button:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  width: calc(100% - 8px);
  height: calc(100% - 8px);;
  background: #ffffff22 url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg width='100%' height='100%' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><rect rx='20px' width='100%' height='100%' x='2' y='2' style='width: calc(100% - 4px); height: calc(100% - 4px); fill: none; stroke: %23FC961E; stroke-width: 4px; stroke-dasharray: 4 12; stroke-linecap: round'/></svg>") no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">I am button</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
.button{
  position: relative;
  background: #CE3900;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 30px;
  color: #FC961E;
}

.button:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  width: calc(100% - 12px);
  height: calc(100% - 12px);;
  background: #ffffff22;
  border: 3px dashed orange;
  border-radius: 30px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="button">I am button</div>
```

Do you really have to use the svg? or could you maybe do something like this?

```
<div class="button">I am button</div>


.button{
  position: relative;
  background: #CE3900;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 30px;
  color: #FC961E;
}

.button:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  width: calc(100% - 12px);
  height: calc(100% - 12px);;
  background: #ffffff22;
  border: 3px dashed orange;
  border-radius: 30px;
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use css border, I need certain property  `stroke-dasharray: 4 12;` with rounded dashes - it is required condition

Comment: I found a solution - [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1t4qgrbs/), but I'm not sure that this is the best solution

Answer (score -1):

Just use

```
border: 3px dashed red
```

it will create the button you need no need to use SVG, this approch is light for DOM rendering and dose the same work in less number of code line

Comment: It is not for me, I need to use properties `stroke-dasharray: 4 12; stroke-linecap: round`